# In a Jupyter notebook, trying to play some musical notes in real time using python

Tags: python

I need some simple way to have a note play, given the pitch, duration and volume. I'd like to do it in the moment I call the function, not to play pre-made audio files, because among other things I'd like to generate random notes or durations on the fly, on a Jupyter notebook, in order to tie in sounds with other data and concepts I'll be working with.

I haven't found a way to do this easily in any module. Simple instrument control would be nice, but at this point I'd settle for just a sine wave. I'd like to be able to do something like:

`playNote('F#',1000,2)`

or

`playNote(46,1000,2) # middle F# is 46 in midi, I believe`

and have it play an F# for 1000 miliseconds at a volume 2 on some scale.

Is this possible to do? I've been trying mingus but it seems geared towards analyzing or composing tracks, not just playing one note. Thanks in advance.

I tried using mingus, fluidsynth, pyfluidsynth, and either did not understand how to get what I was looking for or gave up after failing to install it somewhere.

I'm an experienced professional musician, but have only started programming more seriously this year, as I'm taking the second semester of a programming course, in Python, using Anaconda on Windows 10. As such, everything that involves command line stuff is a lot of trial-and-error for me.

I'm looking for something where if it creates an external audio file, it's all done behind the scenes, and the user just asks for notes one at a time which are played immediately.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is only one problem, the rest is context.